# How to change the cross below the marker (Google Map V3)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

[image: How to change the cross below the marker?]

How to change the cross below the marker?

Comment: What does your code look like? Is your Marker draggable? Do you want to remove the cross when dragging? `crossOnDrag boolean If false, disables cross that appears beneath the marker when dragging. This option is true by default.` From the [MarkerOptions documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

Comment: @geocodezip I want to replace him in the circle. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API-based option to change the cross.

There is a possible CSS-workaround:

```
img[src^='https://mts.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/directions_drag_cross']{
    /*your custom image, 16*16, used as background*/
  background:url(http://i.imgur.com/FKMkIVQ.png);
    /*give the default-image a large width, 
         it will be cropped to 16*16, so the cross will disappear*/
  width:200px !important;
  height:200px !important;
}
```

The problem: the image-src of the cross may change someday, then the selector wouldn't match anymore.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/m58A7/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/m58A7/)

A better  way would be to disable the cross and observe dragstart and dragend to apply a different marker(with a custom cross ) while dragging.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest way to do this using set raiseOnDrag: false for marker options.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: latLng,
title: 'Point A',
map: map,
draggable: true,
raiseOnDrag: false
```

});

Comment: Thank you. Been looking everywhere for this.